# parse youtube video id from string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

hello I found lots of threads here which explains how to parse youtube id from url but nothing I found which can extract youtube video id from string.

I need a function which can return me youtube video id from url

For Example I have string

```
> Hello this is my string and this is my youtube video : http://youtube.com/w=abcdef and this is my blog http://stackoverflow.com etc etc.
```

and it should return

```
> Hello this is my string and this is my youtube video : abcdef and this is my blog http://stackoverflow.com etc etc.
```

> Trying this function but not working properly

```
function linkifyYouTubeURLs(text) {
    var re = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig;
    return text.replace(re,
        '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1">YouTube link: $1</a>');
}
```

Comment: Mr Gates, would you be kind enough to provide and example of one function your tried? :-)

Comment: sure 1 min. I'll edit

Comment: How did you get the link `http://youtube.com/w=abc`, you sure it is correct? I tried replacing "abc" with video id and the link is still not working.

Comment: sorry correct link is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnm8f6Wavk

Comment: `linkifyYouTubeURLs( "My youtube video : http://youtube.com/watch?v=bRnm8f6Wavk and my blog etc." )` gives me your expected result.  What is the real problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var re = /(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^"&?\/ ]{11})/i;
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uP9xY1/2)**

Comment: it would be great if you can provide me some example as I tried so many regex before and it works but can't get my expected output